Wordpress / Elementor How to pass data from one site to another
I have a problem. I have one page that has a slider and a button. On the second page, I would like to read what value the user sent. I tried to do it using cookies and session, but the problem occurs when I want to display the data on the second page. The second page is as if delayed and shows the previous value.
// SOLVED. The answer is in the comment.

Looks like the second page is opening before your ajax call finishes processing.  I recommend opening the window to the second page, only after your ajax call returns.
Change button code to be:
<button id="button">Open New Tab With SESSION</button>

Change jQuery bits to be:
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#button').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: `${window.location.origin}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, 
            data: { action: 'set_session_variable', buttonValue: test.value }, 
        success: function(response) { 
            console.log('SESSION set successfully');
            console.log(test.value);
            window.open('https://*****.com/second_page/', '_blank');
        } 
            
        }); 
        
    });


window.open inside JQuery solved the problem. Thank you. :)
